# Declare public IWebBrowser to access across functions

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I want to be able to call methods but unsure how to decalre my IWebDriver?

```
public class xxxx
{

   [TestMethod]
   public void xxxx()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("");

     
    }
      
    public void xxxx()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("");

       
    }
   
    public void xxxx()
     {




     }
```

I'm having to call the web driver per method but this is opening a different browser each time. Do I need to set the web driver public in the class then call this per method?

Tried to set the IWebDriver as public then create a var per method but unsure how to write this

Comment: add the ChromeDriver that you are using as parameter for your function like public `void xxxx(mychromeBrwoser)`

Comment: Is this [tag:mstest] for a unit test framework?

Answer (score 0):

The `[TestMethod]` attribute leads me to believe you are using MS Test for a unit test provider. If this is incorrect, I can amend my answer.

---

I find a common base class for all of my tests to be a useful place to initialize a web driver:

```
public abstract class SeleniumTest
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    protected IWebDriver Driver
    {
        get
        {
            if (driver == null)
            {
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
        }
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void DestroyDriver()
    {
        if (driver != null)
        {
            driver.Quit();
            driver.Dispose();
            driver = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Using it means deriving your test classes from this common base class:

```
[TestClass]
public class YourTest : SeleniumTest
{                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        Driver.Navigate.GoToUrl("...");
    }   ^^^^^^
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that you lazily initialize the web driver by calling the `Driver` property. Tests that fail before you need a browser window will fail faster, because they don't need to wait for the browser window to open just to find out some database setup routine failed. The trick is to use a `[TestCleanup]` method to quit and dispose of the driver if it has been created.